# List/Get Q_PROPERTY's of derived class only

Tags: c++, qt, qproperty

Imagine a `QObject` derived class:

```
class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT;
    Q_PROPERTY(bool myBool READ myBool WRITE setMyBool);
    //...
}
```

How do I receive all the properties of the derived class `MyObject` only without any of the base classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code snippet from the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetaobject.html#propertyCount), one can list the properties of the derived class only:

```
const QMetaObject* metaObject = myObj->metaObject();
QStringList properties;
for(int i = metaObject->propertyOffset(); i < metaObject->propertyCount(); ++i)
    properties << QString::fromLatin1(metaObject->property(i).name());
```

This should work with Qt 4, 5 and 6. Tested with Qt 4.8.